# MongoDB Nested OR/AND Where?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to figure out how to do nested OR/AND where queries like what you would do in MySQL

Take for example

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    id
FROM
    table
WHERE
   (
       province = "nb" OR
       province = "on"
   ) AND (
       city = "toronto" AND
       first_name = "steven"
   )
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The query in MongoDB looks like:

```
Database.collection_name.find(
    // This is the condition
    {
        $and: [
           {
               $or: [
                   {province: 'nb'},
                   {province: 'on'}
               ]
           },
           {
               city: "toronto"
           },
           {
               first_name: "steven"
           }
        ]
    },

    // Specify the fields that you need
    {
        first_name: 1,
        _id: 1
    }
)
```

Documentation for [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Some examples and the official documentation for MongoDB find [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

Comment: I've edited the answer so that it contains the exact query for your question.