# JS/Mongo Query with more than one $or in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I'm currently trying to generate a query from webservice from mongo. I hve something like this

```
'query' :
{ 
'startDate':{ '$lte':'2016-04-05T00:00:00.000Z' },
'$or':
  [
    { 'endDate': { '$gte': '2016-04-05T00:00:00.000Z' } }, 
    { 'endDate': { '$exists': false }}
  ]
}
```

My question is, is it possitble to add another set of '$or' into this json?

If so how do I do it? (ie. how do i create another $or key inside query)

So it becomes something like this

```
'query' :
{ 
'startDate':{ '$lte':'2016-04-05T00:00:00.000Z' },
'$or':
  [
    { 'endDate': { '$gte': '2016-04-05T00:00:00.000Z' } }, 
    { 'endDate': { '$exists': false }}
  ]
'$or':
  [  { <field> : <value>, <field> : <value> } ]
}
```

Thanks and Regards,
Kev

Comment: How would the query look like as a logical expression? What I mean is what type of operator would combine both $or? Why do you need it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Nested OR/AND Where?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118434/mongodb-nested-or-and-where)

Comment: it would look like this: startDate < '2016-04-05' AND (end date > '2016-04-05 or endDate is null) AND (field1=value1 or field2=value2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new `$and` operator with two `$or`:

```
{ 
  'startDate':{ '$lte':'2016-04-05T00:00:00.000Z' },
  '$and': [
     {
       $or:[
         { 'endDate': { '$gte': '2016-04-05T00:00:00.000Z' } }, 
         { 'endDate': { '$exists': false }}
       ]
    },
    {
      '$or': [
         { <field> : <value>, <field> : <value> }
       ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, i can have $or key in each index of array.